# Find $a$ and $b$ such that $2\cos^2(x+\frac{b}2)-2\sin(ax-\frac\pi2)\cos(ax-\frac\pi2)=1$ for all real $x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all real numbers $a$ and $b$ so that for all real numbers $x$ $$2\cos^2\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)-2\sin\left(ax-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(ax-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$$

It can be simplified to

$$2\cos^2\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)-\sin(2ax-\pi)=1$$

Though from here, I am lost.

What's a proper solution/method to find all possible values for $a$ and $b$ for above? I've tried proceeding with trial and error to give me a better idea but I was unable to make any significant steps.

Comment: Hint: $2\cos^2\theta-1=\cos2\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further reduce

$$2\cos^2\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)-\sin(2ax-\pi)=1$$

to

$$\cos\left(2x+b\right)+\sin(2ax)=0$$

and in product form

$$2\sin\left( (1+a)x+\frac b2+\frac\pi4\right)
\sin\left( (1-a)x+\frac b2-\frac\pi4\right)=0$$

which leads to two sets of values below

$$a=-1, b=2\pi n -\frac\pi2, \>\>\>\text{or} \>\>\>a=1,b=2\pi n +\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to linearise the equation in order to obtain an equation such as the standard $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$, where $f$ is one of $\sin, \cos$ or $\tan$.

Here, it is not very long doing some trigonometry:

- $\sin((2ax-\pi)=\cos((2ax-\pi)-\frac\pi2)$,
- $2\cos^2\bigl(x+\frac b2\bigr)=1+\cos(2x+b)$,
  so you obtain the equation
  $$\cos(2x+b)=\cos(2ax-\tfrac{3\pi}2)=\cos(2ax+\tfrac\pi 2).$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Using the fact that

$$2\cos^2(t)-1=\cos(2t)$$
and
$$\sin(t-\pi)=\cos(t+\frac{\pi}{2})$$
your condition becomes
$$\cos(2x+b)=\cos(2ax+\frac{\pi}{2})$$

So, you see that, we can take

$$a=1\; \text{ and } b=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=2\cos^2(x+b/2)-2\sin(ax-\pi/2)\cos(ax-\pi/2)=[1+\cos(2x+b)]-
\sin(2ax-\pi)$$
Let $a=1$ and $b=\pi/2$, then
$$\implies f(x)=1-\sin 2x+\sin 2x=1$$